# serialization of xml file in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, filestream

I have Following data structure

```
Public Class MeasData
Public Number As Integer
Public Amp As Single
Public Fall As Single
Public Width As Single
Public setPRF As Integer
Public Volt As Single
Public setWidth As Single
```

Serializer Class Code

```
Public Class TestDataSerializer
Public PulsTestData As New List(Of PulserMeasData)
Private PulsTestDataSorted As New SortedList(Of Integer, PulserMeasData)

Public Sub AddPulsTestData(ByVal ChaNum As Integer,
                           ByVal PAmp As Single,
                            ByVal PFallTime As Single,
                            ByVal PWidth As Single,
                            ByVal setPrf As Integer,
                            ByVal setVoltage As Single,
                            ByVal setPulswidth As Single)

    Dim Data As New PulserMeasData(ChaNum, PAmp, PFallTime, PWidth, setPrf, setVoltage, setPulswidth)

    If PulsTestDataSorted.ContainsKey(ChaNum) Then
        PulsTestDataSorted(ChaNum) = Data
    Else
        PulsTestDataSorted.Add(ChaNum, Data)
    End If
    PulsTestData = PulsTestDataSorted.Values.ToList ' XML Serializer can not handle SortedLists
    Dim serializer As New XMLSerializer(GetType(List(Of PulserMeasData)))
    Using file As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open("obj.xml", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
        serializer.Serialize(file, PulsTestData)
    End Using
End Sub
```

End Class

I Want to Generate XML from the above Data Strucuture with different values of set width prf and voltage

Comment: Interesting that this exact question was posted yesterday under a different user name. The post contained some comments that included a link to some code, which could have been adapted for the XML serialization.

Comment: @Eric Tuco have a look at this link OR search convert txt to xml code https://analysistabs.com/vba/code-convert-excel-to-xml/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Module Module1
    Const INPUT_FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Const OUTPUT_FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test1.xml"
    Sub Main()
        'read data
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME)
        Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(PulserMeasDataPA))
        Dim PulserMeasDataPA As PulserMeasDataPA = serializer.Deserialize(reader)

        Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME)

        serializer.Serialize(writer, PulserMeasDataPA)

        Dim PulsTestData As New List(Of PulserMeasData)
        Dim PulsTestDataSorted As New SortedList(Of Integer, PulserMeasData)

        Dim newPulseData As New PulserMeasDataPA()
        Dim newListData As New List(Of TestData)
        newPulseData.TestData = newListData



        For Each PD In PulsTestDataSorted.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Key)
            Dim newTestData As New TestData()
            newListData.Add(newTestData)
            newTestData.PortNumber = PD.Key

            newTestData.MeasureValues = New List(Of MeasureValues)

            For Each testData In PD
                Dim newValues As New MeasureValues
                newTestData.MeasureValues.Add(newValues)

                newValues.Amplitude = testData.Value.Amplitude

            Next
        Next

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class PulserMeasData
    Public ChannelNumber As Integer
    Public Amplitude As Single
    Public Fall As Single
    Public Width As Single
    Public setPRF As Integer
    Public setVoltage As Single
    Public setWidth As Single
End Class

Public Class PulserMeasDataPA
    <XmlElement()>
    Public TestData As List(Of TestData)
End Class
Public Class TestData
    Public PortNumber As Integer
    <XmlArray("Measurement")>
    <XmlArrayItem("MeasureValues")>
    Public MeasureValues As List(Of MeasureValues)
End Class
Public Class MeasureValues
    Public Amplitude As String
    Public Fall As String
    Public Width As String
    Public setWidth As Decimal
    Public PRF As Decimal
    Public Volt As Decimal
End Class
```

Here is the XML file I used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PulserMeasDataPA>
  <TestData>
    <PortNumber>1</PortNumber>
    <Measurement>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          40</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            1000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              100</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          100</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            1000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              100</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          40</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            5000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              50</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          100</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            5000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              50</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
    </Measurement>
  </TestData>
  <TestData>
    <PortNumber>2</PortNumber>
    <Measurement>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          40</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            1000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              100</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          100</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            1000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              100</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          40</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            5000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              50</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
      <MeasureValues>
        <Amplitude></Amplitude>
        <Fall></Fall>
        <Width></Width>
        <setWidth>
          100</setWidth>
          <PRF>
            5000</PRF>
            <Volt>
              50</Volt>
            </MeasureValues>
    </Measurement>
  </TestData>
</PulserMeasDataPA>
```

Comment: can you please tell me where is is implementing the logic of setWidth which I have mentioned above? i.e. writing all the width values with prf and volt and when width values is completed once in next data set it will update the prf and volt ... can you please explain little bit?

Comment: Run the code and the put break point after the variable PulserMeasDataPA is loaded.  You will see all the classes and properties.

Comment: Dim serializer As XMLSerializer = New XMLSerializer(GetType(PulserMeasDataPA)) 
Getting Error at this line : Type Expected BC30182.

Comment: The type is the classes below the module.  You should not be getting this error.

Comment: Yes i can see from the code PulserMeasDataPA is passed as type but still i am getting this Error :(

Comment: Do you have import statements at top of module?  Is file in correct location?

Comment: Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

i have just these 2 imports in my file

Comment: If one has "Option Strict" enabled , the above code won't compile. Change `serializer.Deserialize(reader)` to either `DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), PulserMeasDataPA)` or `CType(serializer.Deserialize(reader), PulserMeasDataPA)`.

Comment: @user9938 Dim serializer As XMLSerializer = New XMLSerializer(GetType(PulserMeasDataPA)) Problem is with this line the one you mentioned above is working fine. i am getting the error at(XMLSerializer ) this

Comment: The XML expected output contains errors so I posted the corrected XML file.  Try with my XML file.  The slashes in the closing tags are in the wrong place in the original xml file.

Comment: Actually the problem is not with xml or anything. the problem is with only this line 

Dim serializer As XMLSerializer = New XMLSerializer(GetType(PulserMeasDataPA))

and the Error is namespace xml serializer type expected

Comment: The capital letters are wrong. My code has XmlSerializer while yours has XMLSerializer.

Comment: @jdweng It Worked. Thanks Really appreciated. I have one question in case I don't want it to read the data first from the xml and then write it to the xml. If i only want to get data from user and then want to store it to xml in the format which I  mentioned... How it will be I mean like this 
Dim data As PulserMeasDataPA = New PulserMeasDataPA(// List of the data here)

You have used nested lists which for me is little difficult to understand i.e. how can i provide the hard code data and store it to the required xml form. 

Thanks :)

Comment: Dim newPulseData As New PulserMeasDataPA()
        newPulseData.TestData = New List(Of TestData)
        Dim newData As New TestData()
        newPulseData.TestData.Add(newData)

Comment: @jdweng this code is ignoring many tags and varaibles inside the MeasureValues class

Comment: I just gave example of how to create the classes before writing.  You have to write to the classes with values.  Like newPulseData.TestData.PortNumber = 1  You also need newPulseData.TestData.MeasuredValues = New List(Of MeasureValues)

Comment: @jdweng this is where actually i am confused because i dont know then how this XMLArray and XMLArrayItem will work with this :(

Comment: @jdweng can you please help me with this i.e. to write the values to the classes here I am confused because of nested lists in classes and XMLArray and XMLArrayItem elements. :(  so that I can passed it to serializer and I don't need to read it first from the xml. would be really helpful for me :)

Comment: `XMLArray` and `XMLArrayItem` are for use by XmlSerializer. Since that part has been written for you, you can ignore it while you work on the next part. Focus on `List(Of TestData)` and `List(Of MeasureValues)`. What are you going to do with those? How are you going to create a new instance of each of those? How are you going to add values?

Comment: I updated code to show how to add data